Blazor WASM and remote debugging
I am using Rider to develop Blazor WASM application, sucesfully, without issues. I would like to remote debug it, but I am yet to find a conclusive way to start up a remote debug connection to the blazor application.
The thing is, I have cookie-based authentication under Laravel, which ultimately serves as a direct host of my blazor application. So I don't have to separate the workflows and deal with CORS and many other settings, it would be very best if I could just connect to my built application with Debug symbols that a remote Laravel server hosts, and not deal with two separate domains where one is my Laravel server+API and the other is my Blazor WASM serving protocol from Rider.
Has any one of you ideas how to approach this ? I note that I would be very glad if I could just get past the hussle of separating frontend from my backend.
In the past days, I came up empty-handed... I read an extensive blog about how Rider works in Debug session under the hood here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/11/07/how-jetbrains-rider-implemented-net-webassembly-debugging/, but it came up to no help.
I also have been unable to start Chromium based devtool under the Laravel hosted app, as my 127.0.0.1:8000/app/_framework/debug?url= gets me 404.
Classic workflow of debugging under the Rider umbrella works as expected, of course.
EDIT: I also tried VS Code, and for that I created this configuration
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach and Debug",
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "request": "attach",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/",
            "browser": "chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/wwwroot",
            "timeout": 30000,
        }
    ],

but after those 30 seconds, I get:
unable to launch browser, could not open ws://127.0.0.1:8000/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser=.......

There seems to be no /app/ dir, even though both wwwroot/index.html and deployed (using -c Debug option) site also uses <base href="/app/" />

Make sure Blazor debug proxy is running and you can access at /app/_framework/debug.you could try Chrome DevTools to debug Blazor WASM  http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/_framework/debug?url=/. and regarding vs code debugging error you double-check the webRoot and url settings in the launch.json configuration. You may need to add explicit routes in Laravel to serve the Blazor _framework debug paths.

If you want to debug a Blazor WASM static webapp which Laravel hosts, it's not possible. You cannot attach the debugger on published WASM currently.
Theoretically, use reverse proxy to rewrite the application URL is allowed. You will need to run the WASM app locally and ensure it is accessible through localhost. Rider's debug proxy can then establish connections between the debugger and browser.
If you are only looking to resolve the CORS problem during frontend development, you can add a new record in your host file. For example, use a second-level domain like fake-frontend.yourbackendservice.com and point it to 127.0.0.1. Then, modify the corresponding value of applicationUrl in Blazor's launchSettings.json. This will resolve the CORS problem and allow Rider to attach to the WASM application.
